# What does "therf werre eyght bokes" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've been told that the following phrase is valid English, although Google Translate marks each of the words as wrong.

> Therf werre eyght bokes.

What does this phrase mean in common English?

Comment: In *common* English, not much. :^)

Comment: Where's it from? It could be a way of writing 'There were eight books' from the time when English spelling showed considerable variation. Even so, 'therf' is unusual.

Comment: The phrase is not valid. It's just that each individual word is valid.

Comment: Why's the downvote?

Comment: The downvote might be because "This question does not show any research effort"; a simple Google search would provide most of what is on here. (But not all; it's not my downvote, though I think it's close to the line.)

Comment: I've downvoted and voted to close because this isn't a question about [English as she is spoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_As_She_Is_Spoke)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Could you help me improve the question. The answers provided by Hugo and TimLymington are exactly what I was looking for (explanation and translation of this absurd phrase).

Comment: @Krom: I don't object to the question having been asked, and I don't disagree with a single word of Hugo's answer. But whilst I don't exactly "begrudge" Hugo getting points (and probably a "Nice Answer" badge) for answering, I'd rather have seen that information given to you in a comment, and the question summarily closed. No amount of editing will make this a question about current English language **usage** - it will always be just an interesting example of the limitations of dumb spell-checkers.

Comment: @Fumble: FWIW, I categorically disagree.  There is a certain logic that says any question of the form "Is this correct English?" is on-topic only if the answer is yes, but surely not on this site.  They **are** English words, but they **don't** form an English phrase; bang on-topic, I'd say.

Comment: @TimLymington: Where would we draw the line? Presumably you'd also say it's bang on-topic to ask what ["Colorless green ideas sleep furiously"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously) "means". Actually, if that one turned up, I'd vote to send it to linguistics.se. But putting that aside, surely OP's "word string" here is General Reference anyway - practically all Google's results for it are just pointing out how this meaningless sequence can in fact get through (certain) spell-checkers.

Comment: "I've been told" is not research. Sorry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*"Therf werre eyght bokes"* isn't a grammatically correct sentence.

It's used as an example on a [number](https://www.itprotoday.com/data-analytics-and-data-management) of [websites](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040402-00/?p=39923) and [books](https://books.google.fi/books?id=wYrCitbs5PQC&pg=PT45&lpg=PT45&dq=Therf%20werre%20eyght%20bokes&source=bl&ots=VpdGmTI-aC&sig=I338CU2ici5ihuU2VgHECETv4C8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pwpfT6iuEqH64QTu1bXHBw#v=onepage&q=Therf%20werre%20eyght%20bokes&f=true) to show that having a really large spell-checker dictionary isn't necessarily a good thing because if your spell-checker contained every word in the Oxford English Dictionary then *"Therf werre eyght bokes"* would be shown as correct.

The sentence looks similar to *"There were eight books"*, but the original is a deliberate example of an incorrect or nonsense sentence.

Comment: *Therf* (or tharf) is Northumberland dialect for unleavened: *boke* (as well as a Chaucerian spelling) is Lancashire dialect for 'to push or poke'.

Comment: And apparently *eyght* is a form of *eyot* (island), and *werre* is an alternative spelling for: *were, war, waur, ware, wary, warre* (a knot in timber), *weary, weir*, or *vere* (springtime). Also, indirectly, of *worst* (as a verb), and *aware*.  Probably just as well it's no longer in use.

Comment: @TimLymington: These are interesting additions I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: *Boke* is also a Scots/Ulster term for vomit